# Descrições das medalhas não traduzidas

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução

Não sei se foi após a atualização do site, mas há algumas descrições de medalhas que não estão traduzidas.

### - Bronze

- Conversador
- Professor
- Pressão dos colegas
- Comentador
- Capelo
- Revisor
- Autodidata
- Guardião
- Ressurgimento
- Escavador
- Disciplinado

### - Prata

- Dever Cívico
- Assistente de pesquisa
- Taxonomista
- Entusiasta
- Generalista
- Necromante
- Conhecedor
- Representante
- Espírito Esportivo

### - Ouro

- Eleitorado
- Fanático
- Legendário
- Reversão
- Administrador
- Marechal
- Revisor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pela minha busca rápida, todas as descrições já foram traduzidas mas estão na imensa fila de revisões do Transifex. Somos apenas 3 revisores, e a revisão não é um processo rápido em grande parte dos casos, porque não queremos aprovar coisas das quais não temos certeza.

Vou percorrer essas e revisar tudo. Daqui a pouco deve estar tudo no site.

## Atualização:

*Acho* que encontrei tudo. Vai pro ar no próximo build!

Comment: A medalha professor não foi traduzida.